# How to use Soundex() in googlecolab for python?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, fuzzy, soundex

I do coding using Python I tried to use soundex() in googlecolab by importing fuzzy . But I can not use . Pl. guide

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please give an idea, what have you tried so far. What is the specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `!pip install fuzzy` before `import fuzzy` in colab and you should be able to use `soundex()`